# Postgres Query not selecting index for a column with OR condition

Tags: postgresql

I have a query where the Postgres is performing a Hash join with sequence scan instead of an Index join with Nested loop, when I use an OR condition.  This is causing the query to take 2 seconds instead of completing in < 100ms.  I have run VACUUM ANALYZE and have rebuilt the index on the PATIENTCHARTNOTE table (which is about 5GB) but its still using hash join.  Do you have any suggestions on how I can improve this?

```
explain analyze
SELECT Count (_pcn.id) AS total_open_note
FROM   patientchartnote _pcn
   INNER JOIN appointment _appt
           ON _appt.id = _pcn.appointment_id
   INNER JOIN patient _pt
           ON _pt.id = _appt.patient_id
   LEFT OUTER JOIN person _ps
                ON _ps.id = _pt.appuser_id
   WHERE  _pcn.active = true
   AND _pt.active = true
   AND _appt.datecomplete IS NULL
   AND _pcn.title IS NOT NULL
   AND _pcn.title <> ''
   AND ( _pt.assigned_to_user_id = '136964'
         OR  _pcn.createdby_id = '136964'
   );


 Aggregate  (cost=237655.59..237655.60 rows=1 width=8) (actual       time=1602.069..1602.069 rows=1 loops=1)
 ->  Hash Join  (cost=83095.43..237645.30 rows=4117 width=4) (actual time=944.850..1602.014 rows=241 loops=1)
 Hash Cond: (_appt.patient_id = _pt.id)
 Join Filter: ((_pt.assigned_to_user_id = 136964) OR (_pcn.createdby_id = 136964))
 Rows Removed by Join Filter: 94036
 ->  Hash Join  (cost=46650.68..182243.64 rows=556034 width=12) (actual time=415.862..1163.812 rows=94457 loops=1)
 Hash Cond: (_pcn.appointment_id = _appt.id)
 ->  Seq Scan on patientchartnote _pcn  (cost=0.00..112794.20 rows=1073978 width=12) (actual time=0.016..423.262 rows=1
073618 loops=1)
Filter: (active AND (title IS NOT NULL) AND ((title)::text <> ''::text))
Rows Removed by Filter: 22488
->  Hash  (cost=35223.61..35223.61 rows=696486 width=8) (actual time=414.749..414.749 rows=692839 loops=1)
Buckets: 131072  Batches: 16  Memory Usage: 2732kB
->  Seq Scan on appointment _appt  (cost=0.00..35223.61 rows=696486 width=8)        (actual time=0.010..271.208 rows=69
2839 loops=1)
Filter: (datecomplete IS NULL)
Rows Removed by Filter: 652426
->  Hash  (cost=24698.57..24698.57 rows=675694 width=12) (actual time=351.566..351.566 rows=674929 loops=1)
Buckets: 131072  Batches: 16  Memory Usage: 2737kB
->  Seq Scan on patient _pt  (cost=0.00..24698.57 rows=675694 width=12) (actual time=0.013..197.268 rows=674929 loops=
1)
Filter: active
Rows Removed by Filter: 17426
Planning time: 1.533 ms
Execution time: 1602.715 ms
```

When I replace "OR  _pcn.createdby_id = '136964'" with "AND  _pcn.createdby_id = '136964'", Postgres performs an index scan

```
 Aggregate  (cost=29167.56..29167.57 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=937.743..937.743 rows=1 loops=1)
 ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.28..29167.55 rows=7 width=4) (actual time=19.136..937.669 rows=37 loops=1)
 ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.85..27393.03 rows=1654 width=4) (actual time=2.154..910.250 rows=1649 loops=1)
 ->  Index Scan using patient_activeassigned_idx on patient _pt  (cost=0.42..3075.00 rows=1644 width=8) (actual time=1.
599..11.820 rows=1627 loops=1)
 Index Cond: ((active = true) AND (assigned_to_user_id = 136964))
 Filter: active
 ->  Index Scan using appointment_datepatient_idx on appointment _appt  (cost=0.43..14.75 rows=4 width=8) (actual time=
 0.543..0.550 rows=1 loops=1627)
 Index Cond: ((patient_id = _pt.id) AND (datecomplete IS NULL))
 ->  Index Scan using patientchartnote_activeappointment_idx on patientchartnote _pcn  (cost=0.43..1.06 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.014..0.014 rows=0 loops=1649)
 Index Cond: ((active = true) AND (createdby_id = 136964) AND (appointment_id = _appt.id) AND (title IS NOT NULL))
 Filter: (active AND ((title)::text <> ''::text))
 Planning time: 1.489 ms
 Execution time: 937.910 ms
 (13 rows)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `OR` in SQL queries usually results in bad performance.

That is because – different from `AND` – it does not restrict, but extend the number of rows in the query result. With `AND`, you can use an index scan for one part of the condition and further restrict the result set with a filter on the second condition. That is not possible with `OR`.

So PostgreSQL does the only thing left: it computes the whole join and then filters out all rows that do not match the condition. Of course that is very inefficient when you are joining three tables (I didn't count the outer join).

Assuming that all columns called `id` are primary keys, you could rewrite the query as follows:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM
    (SELECT _pcn.id
     FROM   patientchartnote _pcn
        INNER JOIN appointment _appt
                ON _appt.id = _pcn.appointment_id
        INNER JOIN patient _pt
                ON _pt.id = _appt.patient_id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN person _ps
                     ON _ps.id = _pt.appuser_id
        WHERE  _pcn.active = true
        AND _pt.active = true
        AND _appt.datecomplete IS NULL
        AND _pcn.title IS NOT NULL
        AND _pcn.title <> ''
        AND _pt.assigned_to_user_id = '136964'
     UNION
     SELECT _pcn.id
     FROM   patientchartnote _pcn
        INNER JOIN appointment _appt
                ON _appt.id = _pcn.appointment_id
        INNER JOIN patient _pt
                ON _pt.id = _appt.patient_id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN person _ps
                     ON _ps.id = _pt.appuser_id
        WHERE  _pcn.active = true
        AND _pt.active = true
        AND _appt.datecomplete IS NULL
        AND _pcn.title IS NOT NULL
        AND _pcn.title <> ''
        AND _pcn.createdby_id = '136964'
    ) q;
```

Even though this is running the query twice, indexes can be used to filter out all but a few rows early on, so this query should perform better.