# Postgres - Is "not exists" slower than join?

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization

I'm trying to locate the cause of a slow query that hits 3 tables with records ranging from a few hundred thousand to a several million

- tango - 6166101
- kilo_golf - 822805
- three_romeo - 535782

**Version**

- PostgreSQL 11.10

**Current query**

```
select count(*) as aggregate
from "tango"
where "lima" = juliet
  and not exists(select 1
                 from "three_romeo" quebec_seven_oscar
                 where quebec_seven_oscar.six_two = tango.six_two
                   and quebec_seven_oscar."romeo" >= six_seven
                   and quebec_seven_oscar."three_seven" in
                       ('partial_survey', 'survey_completed', 'wrong_number', 'moved'))
  and ("mike" <= '2021-02-03 13:26:22' or "mike" is null)
  and not exists(select 1
                 from "kilo_golf" as "delta"
                 where "delta"."to" = tango.six_two
                   and "two" = november
                   and "delta"."romeo" >= '2021-02-05 13:49:15')
  and not exists(select 1
                 from "three_romeo" as "four"
                 where "four".foxtrot = tango.quebec_seven_victor
                   and "four"."three_seven" in ('deceased', 'block_calls', 'block_all'))
  and "tango"."yankee" is null;
```

This is the analysis of the query in its current state - https://explain.depesz.com/s/Di51

It feels like the problematic area is in the `tango` table

- tango.lima is equal to 'juliet' in the majority of records (low cardinality), we don't currently have an index on this
- The long filter makes me wonder if I should create some sort of composite index?

After reading another post (https://stackoverflow.com/a/50148594/682754) tried removing the `or "mike" is null` and this helped quite a lot

https://explain.depesz.com/s/XgmB

Should I try and remove the not exists in favour of using joins?

Thanks

Comment: You could store `-infinity` in the column `mike` then you can get rid of the `or is null` condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that using explicit joins will help you, since PostgreSQL converts `NOT EXISTS` into an anti-join anyway.

But you spotted the problem: it is the `OR`. I would recommend that you use a dynamic query: add the cindition only if `mike`is not NULL rather than having a static query with `OR`.

Comment: Well I think it was your answer to the linked post that helped spot the problem ;)
`mike` is essentially a `last_updated` field that we want to get record last_updated more than a few hours ago OR are null. Is a dynamic query suitable for that in this situation?

Comment: Sure. Add the condition only if `mike` is not NULL.

Comment: Not sure I follow exactly...would dynamic query work if I had some sort of input that would allow me to add the condition (or not).
A shortened version of the query is `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM people WHERE ("last_loaded" <= '2021-02-03 13:26:22' OR last_loaded IS NULL)`, where I'm trying to get people that were loaded a long time ago or have yet to be loaded (NULL).

Comment: No. The code that composes the query looks like `if (mike != NULL) append(query_string, "AND last_loaded <= '2021-02-03 13:26:22'";`

Answer (score 1):

You are counting about 6 million rows, and that will take some time.  The reason that removing `or "mike" is null` can help so much is that it no longer needs to count the rows where mike is null, which is vast majority of them.

But this is of no use to you if you actually do need to count those rows.  So, do you?  I'm having a hard time picturing a situation in which you need an exact count of 6 million rows often enough that waiting 4 seconds for it is a problem.

Comment: Good point regarding the count, I'll revisit this to check whether it is truly needed